# Why does the number of buffers I create change how they are used?

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics, buffer

We all know what the BufferStrategy does and how it works, but one thing has me scratching my head and I think the answer is right there, but I cannot put my finger on it.

My class is called `A`. `A` `extends` `Canvas` and `implements` `Runnable`

```
public void renderGraphics(){
        createBufferStrategy(2);
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();

        if(bs == null){
             this.createBufferStrategy(2);
             return;
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }
```

Because my class `A` extends Canvas, I am able to call `createBufferStrategy(2)`. 
Then the contents of that are stored into `bs`.

The rest of the method works as intended, my window pops up (I'm not showing all the code of the class because it isn't relevant, it's just a simple program that creates a window and renders a color using the graphics card) and the color of the contents inside the window is red. As intended.

However.. when I change my code to `createBufferStrategy(3)`, number of buffers set from 2, to 3.. the window is displayed but the canvas is not.

To fix this.. I have to change the code to

```
public void render(){
                //REMOVE the createBufferStrategy(3) method from this line
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null){
             this.createBufferStrategy(3);
             return;
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        g.dispose();
        bs.show();

    }
```

My question is why?

What is it that I'm missing here?

TL;DR

Why do I have to delete the `createBufferStrategy(3)` and test if `bs` is `null` in oreder to work with 3 buffers, but with 2, I can just `createBuffer(2)` first and store the contents into `bs` and then just draw?

Comment: *"What is it that I'm missing here?"*  About a decade of advancements in Swing.  Swing (the majority of it) is double-buffered by default, so it makes most previous use of buffer strategies obsolete.